# MySQL row variable out of order

Tags: mysql

I have these 2 MySQL tables:

```
DESCRIBE time;
+---------------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)                             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date          | date                                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

DESCRIBE employee;
+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type                                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)                              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| tid     | int(11)                              | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| salary  | double                               | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| age     | int(11)                              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In the query below, I'm attempting to attach row number for my [salary | date] table. The row number gets reset to 1 as the date changes. Here's my query:

```
SELECT IF(@prev != d.date, @rownum := 1, @rownum := @rownum + 1) AS row, @prev := d.date, e.salary
FROM employee e, time d, (SELECT @rownum := 0, @prev := NULL) r
WHERE e.age >= 18 AND e.age <= 25 AND e.tid = d.id AND d.date >= '2002-01-01' AND d.date <= '2003-01-01'
ORDER BY date, salary;
```

I got the results as shown in the first table below. The row numbers are incorrect. The expected row numbers are shown in the second table below.

```
+------+-----------------+---------+
| row  | @prev := d.date | salary  |
+------+-----------------+---------+
|    6 | 2002-01-01      | 21823.2 |
|    2 | 2002-01-01      |   27279 |
|    9 | 2002-01-01      |   35073 |
|    8 | 2002-01-01      | 36631.8 |
|    4 | 2002-01-01      | 36631.8 |
|    7 | 2002-01-01      |   38970 |
|    5 | 2002-01-01      | 52219.8 |
|    3 | 2002-01-01      |  350730 |
|    1 | 2002-01-01      |  389700 |
|    7 | 2003-01-01      | 21823.2 |
|    2 | 2003-01-01      |   27279 |
|    4 | 2003-01-01      | 31565.7 |
|   10 | 2003-01-01      |   35073 |
|    3 | 2003-01-01      | 36242.1 |
|    9 | 2003-01-01      | 36631.8 |
|    5 | 2003-01-01      | 36631.8 |
|    8 | 2003-01-01      |   38970 |
|    6 | 2003-01-01      | 52219.8 |
|    1 | 2003-01-01      |  389700 |
+------+-----------------+---------+
```

I expected the following results with correct row numbers. Thoughts?

```
+------+-----------------+---------+
| row  | @prev := d.date | salary  |
+------+-----------------+---------+
|    1 | 2002-01-01      | 21823.2 |
|    2 | 2002-01-01      |   27279 |
|    3 | 2002-01-01      |   35073 |
|    4 | 2002-01-01      | 36631.8 |
|    5 | 2002-01-01      | 36631.8 |
|    6 | 2002-01-01      |   38970 |
|    7 | 2002-01-01      | 52219.8 |
|    8 | 2002-01-01      |  350730 |
|    9 | 2002-01-01      |  389700 |
|    1 | 2003-01-01      | 21823.2 |
|    2 | 2003-01-01      |   27279 |
|    3 | 2003-01-01      | 31565.7 |
|    4 | 2003-01-01      |   35073 |
|    5 | 2003-01-01      | 36242.1 |
|    6 | 2003-01-01      | 36631.8 |
|    7 | 2003-01-01      | 36631.8 |
|    8 | 2003-01-01      |   38970 |
|    9 | 2003-01-01      | 52219.8 |
|   10 | 2003-01-01      |  389700 |
+------+-----------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(@prev != date, @rownum := 1, @rownum := @rownum + 1) AS row, 
       @prev := date, salary
  FROM  (SELECT d.date,e.salary
           FROM employee e, time d
          WHERE e.age >= 18 
            AND e.age <= 25 
            AND e.tid = d.id 
            AND d.date >= '2002-01-01' 
            AND d.date <= '2003-01-01'
       ORDER BY date, salary) a, (SELECT @rownum := 0, @prev := NULL) r;
```

Comment: Thanks! This gives the results as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try ordering the result set in an inline view (derived table).  Reference the inline view in an outer query, to assign the rownum:

```
SELECT IF(@prev != t.date, @rownum := 1, @rownum := @rownum + 1) AS `row`
     , @prev := t.date  AS `date`
     , t.salary
  FROM (SELECT @rownum := 0, @prev := NULL) r
 CROSS
  JOIN (   
         SELECT d.date
              , e.salary
           FROM employee e
           JOIN time d 
             ON d.tid = e.tid
          WHERE e.age >=8
            AND e.age <= 25
            AND d.date >= '2002-01-01'
            AND d.date <= '2003-01-01'
          ORDER 
             BY d.date
              , e.salary
       ) t
 ORDER
    BY t.date
     , e.salary
```

For testing, you can run just the query in the inline view (aliased as `t` separately, to verify that the resultset is ordered the way you want it.